# XSLT or viewer app to view "Internet Explorer Network Inspector" xml exports

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools

Using the IE9 Developer Toolbar's network tab, I have captured some navigation around my site and then exported those logs to an XML file (by default NetworkData.xml).

In that XML it has a creator tag set to  "Internet Explorer Network Inspector".

Is there an XSLT that can help with the display of that XML or some viewer application that can help?

**Update:**
Upon future research, the NetworkData.xml file is an xml representation of a HAR file.  There are quite a few online HAR viewers. Still cannot find a viewer for XML-HAR and no converters either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What tools can I use to analyze Internet Explorer's network capture logs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349945/what-tools-can-i-use-to-analyze-internet-explorers-network-capture-logs)

Answer (score 2):

As shown here [What tools can I use to analyze Internet Explorer's network capture logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349945/what-tools-can-i-use-to-analyze-internet-explorers-network-capture-logs) Fiddler seems to do it.
After installation of Fiddler, I saw no more need for it however.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an XLST, is not complete but you'll get the idea.

Edit NetworkData.xml and add

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="NDTable.xsl" ?>
```

at the beginning

Save the following XML at NDTable.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="log">
        <head>
            <Title>
                <xsl:value-of select="creator/name"/>
            </Title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>
                <xsl:value-of select="creator/name" />
            </h1>
            <P>Started at <xsl:value-of select="pages/page/startedDateTime" />
            </P>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Request</th>
                    <th>Response</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="entries" />
            </table>
        </body>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <tr> 
            <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="request" />
            </td>
            <td valig="top">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="response" />
            </td>

        </tr>


    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="request">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <xsl:value-of select="method" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="url" />
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Headers</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="headers/header[not(name='Cookie')]" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Cookies</th>
                        </tr>

                        <xsl:apply-templates select="cookies" />
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="response">
        <table>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="status" /> <span>.</span><xsl:value-of select="statusText" />
                <br/>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Headers</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="headers/header" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
<div style='background-color: #C0C0C0'> <xsl:value-of select="content/text" /> </div>                   
            </td>
        </table>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="header">
        <xsl:value-of select="name" /> : <xsl:value-of select="value" />
        <br/>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="cookie">
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <xsl:value-of select="name" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="value" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```